# Natural Deductions of Propositional Logic and Predicate Logic

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove the following:

1. ¬(A --> B) ⊢ ¬(¬A v B)
2. ¬(¬A v B) ⊢ (A ^ ¬B)
3. ∀x∀y(P(x, y) --> ¬P(x, y)) ⊢ ∀x¬P(x, x)

For the first two, I feel like the first step is try assume the contradiction, but I'm not sure where to go from there.
For the third one, this is what I have:

1. ∀x∀y(P(x, y) --> ¬P(x, y))   premise
2. ∀y(P(a, y) --> ¬P(a, y))   ∀-elimination of line 1
3. (P(a, b) --> ¬P(a, b))   ∀-elimination of line 2
4. P(a, b)                 assumption
5. ¬P(a, b)                arrow-elimination of lines 3 and 4
6. ∀x¬P(x, b)                    ∀-introduction for line 5
7. ∀x∀x¬P(x, x)                 ∀-introduction for line 6
8. ∀x¬P(x, x)                    ∀-elimination for line 7

but I don't know if my step 5 or step 7 work...

Comment: What are your rules for negation?

Comment: Which natural deduction system are you using? Are you allowed to use any tautology in your deduction? I ask this because, if yes, the first derivations is straightforward.

Comment: intro/elimination of conditionals, disjunctions, conjunctions, negations, modus tollens...I can use things as long as I prove them as lemmas before hand

Comment: The predicate logic proof has you generalizing on a letter used in an assumption.  This isn't legal... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization

Comment: @DougSpoonwood so how would I go about proving it?  I realized that I couldn't do many of those steps, so I have no idea where to start ...

Comment: @user146767 Hunan's proof should work.

Comment: @dougspoonwood which one is that?

Comment: The answer given by Hunan Rostomyan below.

Comment: Indeed.  The key is that the conclusion contains only *one* universal quantifier, requiring the assumption of only *one* arbitrary variable; and so *both* universal quantifiers in the premise should be eliminated to that *same* variable.

Answer (score 2):

For the first two, as you said, we proceed indirectly:

> $1.~\lnot(A \rightarrow B) \vdash \lnot(\lnot A \lor B)$

[image]

> $2.~\lnot(\lnot A \lor B) \vdash (A \land \lnot B)$

[image]

> $3.~\forall x \forall y(P(x, y) \rightarrow \lnot P(x, y)) \vdash \forall x \lnot P(x, x)$

This version is a bit different from yours, but the general strategy is the same:

[image]